# Unable to install 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using `VS Professional 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.16) Release`

I am trying install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 1.1.2
```

I am getting the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>   1.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.          0

I googled but didn't find an answer.

I have `Microsoft.Net Framework Version 4.7.02046`
and `Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.16) Release`

Comment: What version of .Net Framework is your project set to use?

Comment: @DavidG - If i look into packages.config, i can find version 'targetFramework="net45"' but if i go to Help > About Microsoft .. i can see version is 4.7.02046 (mentioned in my question). And If i look in Registry editor i can see version is 4.0.0.0 under client Node.

Comment: No, your project will target a Framework version. Right click on the project, select properties, what is the value of the "target framework" property?

Comment: Alright i can see it is '.Net Framework 4.5'

Comment: Change that to 4.7 then

Comment: 4.7 isn't coming in the Target Frameowrk drop down. the latest is 4.6.1

Comment: Then try 4.6.1!

Comment: Yup it worked. Oh i can see on EntityFrameworkCore  package site min .NETFramework 4.5.1. hence it will work for 4.5.1 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project is targetting in incompatible version of .Net Framework. Right click on the project, select properties and note the value of the *Target Framework*. Looking at the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` the oldest version of the .Net Framework you can target is v4.5.1.

To use this package you need to update your project to target 4.5.1 or newer.

Comment: I don't see anything about required .Net version on the package page. Where do I get this info?

Comment: @arrowd Under dependencies, it says it targets.NETStandard 2.1 and you can see the .NET version on the table here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and where I found is that your .Net Core version has to be compatible with the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.
I am using .Net Core 2.1 and I found out that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1 is compatible, I guess you have to try each version if you don't know which one will be the one.

Comment: still the case in 2022, there is no clear matrix about the support of net framework and EF lib